# C - gettimeofday for computing time?

Tags: c

do you know how to use gettimeofday for measuring computing time? I can measure one time by this code:

```
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;

  time_t curtime;



 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
 curtime=tv.tv_sec;

 strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
 printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);
```

This one is made before computing, second one after. But do you know how to subtracts it?

I need result in miliseconds

Comment: `gettimeofday` actually should not be used to measure the elapsed time. Use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` instead. [Here's why](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time)

Comment: what is 'ld' in printf statement? and also why in some program ===>             printf("time = %06lu\n", now.tv_usec); is used? what is 06 within the quotes?

Comment: A very nice site with some good reference and sometimes examples but there are others like wikibooks for one. http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/time_h/clock.php

Comment: @Beginner......
%ld is a format specifier: for long decimal
and %06lu is a format specifier: for long unsigned with 6 leading zeros...
You can read up on printf format specifiers here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `curtime` variable holds the number of seconds since the epoch.  If you get one before and one after, the later one minus the earlier one is the elapsed time in seconds.  You can subtract `time_t` values just fine.

Answer (score 59):

To subtract timevals:

```
gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
/* ... */
gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
long elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000 + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
```

This is assuming you'll be working with intervals shorter than ~2000 seconds, at which point the arithmetic may overflow depending on the types used. If you need to work with longer intervals just change the last line to:

```
long long elapsed = (t1.tv_sec-t0.tv_sec)*1000000LL + t1.tv_usec-t0.tv_usec;
```

Comment: not working, I need miliseconds and it says segmentation fault

Comment: The segmentation fault has nothing to do with this code. It's happening elsewhere.

Comment: I get segmentation fault only with using this code, nevertheless it is not counting in miliseconds

Comment: It counts microseconds. Divide by 1000 if you need milliseconds, but milliseconds are generally considered very very poor time resolution. If you get a segmentation fault you need to show your code or use a debugger to find where it's happening yourself, but it definitely cannot happen due to any of the code I suggested.

Comment: Many problems here - The answer above is poor code (uninitialized memory location) and gettimeofday is a function that is also deprecated.

Comment: @Xofo: What uninitialized memory? Yes gtod is deprecated but people still use it for moderately reasonable reasons. Use `clock_gettime` and divide by 1000 if you prefer.

Comment: @Waypoint did you figure out your seg fault?  Curious because he says "shorter than ~2000 seconds the arithmetic may overflow"..

Answer (score 4):

The answer offered by @Daniel Kamil Kozar is the correct answer - gettimeofday actually should not be used to measure the elapsed time. Use clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) instead.

---

Man Pages say - The time returned by gettimeofday() is affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the system time).  If you need a monotonically increasing clock, see clock_gettime(2).

The Opengroup says - Applications should use the clock_gettime() function instead of the obsolescent gettimeofday() function.

Everyone seems to love gettimeofday until they run into a case where it does not work or is not there (VxWorks) ... clock_gettime is fantastically awesome and portable.

<<

Answer (score 3):

If you want to measure code efficiency, or in any other way measure time *intervals*, the following will be easier:

```
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   clock_t start = clock();
   //... do work here
   clock_t end = clock();
   double time_elapsed_in_seconds = (end - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   return 0;
}
```

hth

Comment: This measures cpu time, not real time, and often has very bad resolution.

Comment: This is good if you want to measure CPU efficiency. If you are measuring something else -- say an I/O operation -- it might be better to use gettimeofday().

Comment: I'm just wondering if he is trying to do benchmark tests. Isn't there a C lib somewhere for that? But of course you're all right. I agree cause I'm learning too. Just please you guys, don't leave off the headers. It's all in the libs we use right?

Answer (score 3):

No. [gettimeofday should NEVER be used to measure time](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time).

This is causing bugs all over the place. Please don't add more bugs.

Comment: @ijt what do you mean? What I linked to lists several already, including dropped connections, reboots, wrong data, and hangs.

Comment: "NEVER be used to measure time" is extremely misleading, even in the first line of that link it says, "should only be used to get the current time if the current wall-clock time is actually what you want."

Sometimes people want to know how long their function took to run, in real time. "NEVER" is hyperbole.

Comment: @EliezerMiron no you *never* want to use gettimeofday if you want to know how *long the function took to run*. You *only* want to use gettimeofday if you want to know *when* it ran, which is a completely different question. You should *never* compare or subtract two outputs from gettimeofday.

Comment: If gettimeofday can give you an accurate reading of when the function ran (in wall-clock time), then why wouldn't it be able to compare two times to see how much wall-clock time the function took to run?

Comment: @EliezerMiron gettimeofday has different requirements and a different use case. It's much more important for its output to be correct according to new information (user commands new time to be set, NTP tooling jumps the time) than for time not to go backwards. It's also more important that it tries to stay (slew) within the corrent wallclock time than it is that it goes up by a second per real second. To measure time *ALL* you want is a timer that goes up one second per second, which is almost completely out of scope for gettimeofday.

Comment: @EliezerMiron if nothing else if you use gettimeofday() you have to handle the case of "negative time has passed". As the blog post says this is not a theoretical problem, but actually breaks TCP connections, reboots databases, crashes CDNs, and hangs `ping`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. What should be used for measuring function time, then, for debugging purposes?

Comment: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, or `CLOCK_BOOTTIME`, depending on if you want "seconds excluding suspend time". "time units", or "seconds, excluding suspend time".