# How to get UTC time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, linux, utc

I tried to use `gettimeofday` function, but it calculates the time passed since the Epoch,
and that's not what I need.

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you need really?

Comment: How is that not what you want ? (you can easily convert the seconds/microseconds in the struct timeval to e.g. a long long of miliseconds)

Comment: Also, you can refer this already answered [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362577/c-gettimeofday-for-computing-time) in stackoverflow

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work for you.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;

  time_t curtime;



  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  curtime=tv.tv_sec;

  strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
  printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `localtime_r`, otherwise it is either very inefficient or not thread-safe.

Comment: `#include <sys/time.h>` (for the gettimeofday) is needed for compilation